# Electrical circuit interpretation

Tags: power-electronics, schematics

I need to understand the main function of this circuit, and to interpret it.
i find something related to this circuit , in a french website (source)
[image: Circuit]

([Source](https://www.zonetronik.com/chargeur-de-batterie-automatique/))

Comment: So ... what's the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Where did you find this circuit?  Any discussion there about its purpose and operation?  What do YOU think it is supposed to do?

Comment: i did not understand what is made for ?

Comment: At a quick glance, it appears to operate K1, or not,  depending on the setting of RV1, but why is anyone's guess...

Comment: i find something related to this circuit  , in a french website . https://www.zonetronik.com/chargeur-de-batterie-automatique/

Comment: If you don't read French, just use translate.google.com. If you don't understand something after reading the webpage, edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: If you can't write a question, we can't answer it. This is a Q&A site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a self-charging device, as the title of the link in the comments implies.

- R1-D1 is a voltage reference using a Zener diode
- R2-R5-RV2-D5 will cause the positive input voltage to drop if the output of U1 is low
- R3-D2 and D3-R4 are status LED's
- D4-R6-Q1 will switch the relay K1 on or off

If the battery voltage is too low, then U1 will switch its output high, causing Q1 to switch on. K1 closes the switch, allowing the battery to be charged again. During this time, D5 is off, and U1 works like a pure comparator. The battery will be charged until the negative input pin of U1 reaches the positive pin, which is at D1's Zener voltage.

When the battery is charged, the output will switch back low. This causes the positive input pin to drop in voltage as R2-R5-RV2-D5 conducts current. The relay switches off and the charging stops. The battery will discharge until the negative input pin drops to the level of the positive input pin, causing the cycle to repeat itself.

Comment: Interesting... do I understand correctly that D5 adds hysteresis to it? If yes then this circuit is much more interesting than I thought it was

Comment: Yes, D5 provides a one-way positive feedback branch to add hysteresis.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main function is to compare battery voltage with threshold.
If voltage is higher, then D2 lights and relay is in default position.
If lower, then D3 lights and relay is activated.

Comment: my initial thought it was over-discharge protection. but with logic like that it does not make sense

Comment: Yea, but seems strange, that nearly discharged battery is additionally loaded by relay coil. At the same time @Sven B's answer makes everything clear.